# A coin is tossed 7 times and results recorded. How many total possible outcomes are there?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

Are there 14 outcomes? Because the coin is tossed 7 times and you get 2 outcomes (head or tail) for each one.

Comment: Using the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), there are $2^7=128$ outcomes, presuming order matters (e.g., HHHHHTT is different from TTHHHHH)

Comment: If you don't care about order, you can get anywhere from $0$ to $7$ heads, so $8$ outcomes.  It is important to specify what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you added seven copies of the number $2$ together to get $14$,

but you need to *multiply* seven copies of the number $2$ together, by the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product),

so there are $2^7=128$ outcomes,

presuming order matters (e.g., HHHHHTT is different from TTHHHHH).

(If order does not matter, then you could get from $0$ to $7$ heads, so there are $8$ outcomes,

as pointed out in a comment by [Ross Millikan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1827/ross-millikan).)

Comment: This is a horrible nitpick, but to compute $2+2+2+2+2+2+2=14$ you add _six_ times, and to compute $2\times2\times2\times2\times2\times2\times2=128$ you multiply six times.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen:  I get what you're saying; I suppose I meant that I added $2$ seven times to the empty sum ($0$) and I multiplied the empty product ($1$) by $2$ seven times; is there a better way I could word it and still use the number $7$ rather than $6$?  the number $7$ is a natural part of the statement, since it's $2\times7$ or $2^7$

Comment: Add/multiply together $7$ copies of the number $2$.